# How to simplify ¬(p → q) → ¬q

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I need to simplify  ¬(p → q) → ¬q to just T. I have gotten it down to p ∧ ¬q → ¬q and im not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Apply the same implication rule and demorgan's law you did to get where you are right now.

Comment: (a) $\neg (p\rightarrow q)$ is equivalent to $p\wedge (\neg q)$ and so,
(b) $p\rightarrow q \equiv (\neg p)\vee q$. Set $P\equiv \neg (p\rightarrow q)$ and $Q\equiv \neg q$ and apply (b) to $P\rightarrow Q$.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
      &\ \ \ \ \ \neg (p \to q)\to \neg q \\
      &\Leftrightarrow (p \to q)\vee \neg q \\
      &\Leftrightarrow (\neg p \vee q)\vee \neg q \\
      &\Leftrightarrow \neg p \vee (q\vee \neg q )\\
      &\Leftrightarrow \neg p \vee T\\
      &\Leftrightarrow T\\
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution:
$$\neg (p \to q)\to \neg q$$
$$\neg(\neg p\vee q)\to\neg q$$
$$(p\wedge \neg q)\to \neg q$$
$$T$$